# Does Simple HTML DOM's clear unset other variables as well

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
$html = str_get_html($htmlStr);
$div = $html->find('div', 0);
$html->clear();
// work with $div
```

In the above example, it seems to throw a 'non-object' error when I try find another element inside the div after the clear. Is that intended behavior from Simple HTML DOM? I would have imagined that it would create a copy of the object when assigned to another variable and that `clear()` would only clear its object.

Do I have to call clear after all usages of copy of the object? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call it intended behavior, it's a clumsy workaround to deal with leaks.